# rich text editor with image hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, rich-text-editor

is there a rich text editor that has image hosting with it?
eg with stackoverflow they are using imgur to host images.

or is there another way eg using an api? im using asp.net mvc/c#

Answer (score 3):

ckeditor(text)+ckfinder(image)

They are the brothers :)

Answer (score 1):

### [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com)

Comment: you should set it up. see documentation: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/File_Browser_%28Uploader%29

Answer (score 0):

Try this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801458/free-image-hosting-with-open-api

There are a few possible options, but you're looking at writing your own connector for the text editor to interface with the API - but having said that, for the most part you'd probably be writing a connector for the image uploading anyway, or at least searching around looking for one that works since most (free) RTEs don't supply file / image upload functionality built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is entirely what you're after, but it might be worth having a look at using Yahoo's YUI editor + Flickr for hosting the images: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/flickr_editor.html

Answer (score 0):

jquery tinymce is a best option. Since there are many plugins for image upload that can be easily integerate into editor

**Tinymce**
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/download/download.php

There would be default image upload. if u need use some third party plugins like this
refer it. http://www.danieloshea.com/products/806-image-selection-and-upload-plugin-for-tinymce

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for free stuff, use FCKEditors, it contains image uploader already plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , this works for me: I used tinymce RTE [roxyfileman](http://www.roxyfileman.com)